# How can we get the object by it's hashcode in java? Is there any existing methode?

Tags: java, object, hashcode

In java，We can use `Object.hashCode()` to get the object's hashcode, that, in turn, can we use the hashcode to get the object? But how? Is there any existing method to solve this problem?

Comment: Get from _where_? Hashcodes aren't unique, what happens in the case of a clash?

Answer (score 1):

Hashcode do not work that way. They are meant to be a hint whether two objects are equal. From `Object` javadoc :

*The general contract of hashCode is:*

- *Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.*
- *If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.*
- *It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.*

As different object may have same hashcode, there cannot exist a way to get an object from its hashcode. If you have such a need, do use a `Map` and store objects with a key. But even there a `Map` will have only one value per key (still from javadoc : *A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value*)